# VBA Paste Cell value if formula contains #REF! Error

Tags: vba, excel

When sending out budget files excel files I need to first copy them to a new book then remove the sections that formulas in the document use to get their values. I do this without calculating so #REF errors appear in the formulas but the values do not #REF until i calculate.

I then want to use these #REF errors as an identifier to search for, copy the cells value (pre calculation) and paste as values so I can keep the value.

I have a solution that works below but this takes upwards of ten minutes.

```
Sub Value_REF2()

'Definitions
Dim lCount As Long
Dim rFoundCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range


'If Error go to Process Error function
On Error GoTo ProcError

    'Remove any #REF in text first to prevent infinite loop in find below
    Set rng = Range("A1:BB999") 'Range may need adjusting based on Grid

    'For Loop
    For Each cell In rng

    If cell.Text = "#REF!" Then
        cell.ClearContents
    End If

    Next cell


    ' Search for #REFs in forumlas
    Set rFoundCell = Range("A1")

            Do
            Set rFoundCell = Cells.Find(What:="#REF", After:=rFoundCell, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
             'Take found cell and copy paste values
             With rFoundCell
                 .Copy
                 .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
             End With

            Loop 'Error will occur, this will trigger ProcError function

'Process Error Function - Exit Sub
ProcError:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

My next solution is below which should be much faster but i just can't work out how to make the IsError look in the actual formula rather than just the cell.

IsError(cell.Formula) does not seem to work?

```
Sub Value()


    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Interactive = False


    Set rng = Range("A1:BB999")

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cell In rng
            If IsError(cell.Formula) Then
                cell.Copy
                cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next cell

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Interactive = True

End Sub
```

The main goal of this is to keep all formulas that do not refer to outside the budget table (like FTE calculations or subtotals and totals) and only value ones that do look outside.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think it should be cell.Value instead of cell.Formula. Give it a try.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Yes I've tried this and still have the same problem, it does not seem to recognize the #Ref unless the cells value is #REF. If the #REF is only in the formula bar it does not work.

Comment: Gotcha. For #REF errors you'll need to use the IsErr function, change the code to `If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsErr(cell.Value) Then`. It handles #REF errors while IsError doesn't.

Comment: ok so my current code for this section is below however this does not find the #REFs in the formula's, it only find the ones that have the cell value as #REF
'For Each cell In rng
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsErr(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Copy
                cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next cell'

Comment: Wouldn't cell.Value2 = cell.Value2 be faster than copying and pasting values?